# React warning render()

Tags: reactjs, warnings

why this happened? 
Warning: render(): Target node has markup rendered by React, but there are unrelated nodes as well. This is most commonly caused by white-space inserted around server-rendered markup.

```
<section id="container-wrapper">
    <div data-reactid=".0.1.0.1">
        loading.....
    </div>
</section>
```

// App.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App routes={routes} /> , document.getElementById('container-wrapper'));
```

Comment: Post your code. Maybe another framework made DOM modification.

Comment: If you're doing serverside rendering wrap your `{{{content}}}` in a DIV element.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it's careless that I add an attribute 'data-reactid' to the div in #container-wrapper. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 34):

I ran into this issue rendering markup server-side. If you have something like this (ejs example):

```
<div id="app">
    <%- markup %>
</div>
```

Try removing all surrounding white space. The following got rid of the warning in my case.

```
<div id="app"><%- markup %></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I figured out that I added a data-reactid attribute in DIV which caused the problem.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the answer m8